# How to apply Newton-Leibnitz formula for derivative in this case? $f\left(x\right)=\int_0^x e^t\sin\left(x-t\right)dt$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to apply Newton-Leibnitz formula for finding $f'(x)$ in this case? $f\left(x\right)=\displaystyle\int_0^xe^t\sin\left(x-t\right)dt$

Two methods I did both gave me different answers, probably doing something wrong fundamentally.
Method 1: $f'(x) = e^x\sin(x-x) = 0$
Method 2: $f\left(x\right)=\displaystyle\int_0^xe^{x-t}\sin\left(t \right)dt=e^x\int_0^xe^{-t}\sin\left(t\right)dt$ which can further be calculated using product rule and which doesn't really equal to $0$

So my question is what am I doing wrong in case $1$? Is there some standard rule or requirement of the newton-leibnitz theorem that I am missing?

Comment: You have an indefinite integral for which the integrated function depends on the parameter which with you are differentiating so you cannot apply the Newton-Leibnitz formula (the function have to be constant w.r.t. the differentiation parameter). For me your second method is the best you can do, you could also have compute manually the growth rate and dominate what can be.

Comment: You should use the more general Leibniz integral rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule This is because both the limit of integration and the integrand depend on $x$.

Comment: @Gary. Thank you very much. This is not covered I guess in calculus courses, is that correct please?

Comment: @Avra I guess it depends on the course and the university.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first method is incomplete.  There are two $x$s in there, so use the chain rule for partial derivatives, with one term for each $x$:

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x e^t\sin(x-t)\;dt =
e^x\sin(x-x) +
\int_0^x e^t \cos(x-t)\;dt
$$

---

Chain rule says:
$$
\frac{d}{dx} G(f(x),g(x)) = G_1(f(x),g(x))f'(x) + G_2(f(x),g(x))g'(x)
$$
where $G_1, G_2$ are the two partial derivaives of $G$.
Apply it with:
$$
G(u,v) = \int_0^u e^t\sin(v-t)\;dt,\quad f(x) = x,\quad g(x) = x .
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can not apply Newton-Leibnitz in case I. Starting from GEdgar answer, you can find the integral by parts as GEdgar did and then take the one that has $\frac{d}{dx}$ to the left side to have $f'(x)$ as this is the trick. You can proceed from there to find your approximation. The point behind Newton-Leibnitz is to find an approximation for the zeros of a function $f(x)=0$, so $b=a-(\frac{f(a)}{f'(a)})$ starts approaching this zero starting from $a$, but I don't see $a$ is given in your question.

In general,

$$x_x=x_{n-1}-\frac{f(x_{n-1})}{f'(x_{n-1})}.$$ A lot of the time $b$ or $x_n$ is a better approximation than $a$ or $x_{n-1}$.